# Transform data based on metadata avoiding for-loops using data.table joins

Tags: r, data.table, metadata

**Problem:** I have the following metadata data.table object. Based on this I want to transform the `extension` and `start_date` columns of the actual data.table `dt` into date columns. I have a solution where I iterate over the rows of the `meta_dt`. As I want to avoid for-loops can you think of a clever `data.table` join?

```
library(data.table)

meta_dt <- data.table(
  col_n = c("id", "description", "extension", "start_date"),
  type = c("character", "character", "date", "date"),
  form = c(NA, NA, "%Y-%m-%d", "%Y-%m-%d")
)

dt <- data.table(
  id = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  description = c("ab", "ac", "ad", "ae"),
  extension = c("2020-01-01", "2020-12-31", "2020-05-01", "2020-01-04"),
  start_date = c("2020-09-01", "2020-11-31", "2020-08-19", "2020-03-14")
)
```

**Expected Outcome:** The structure of the expected outcome shall look like follows (i.e. only the columns specified in metadata as date have been transformed, the other columns are not affected):

```
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  4 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ id         : num  1 2 3 4
 $ description: chr  "ab" "ac" "ad" "ae"
 $ extension  : Date, format: "2020-01-01" "2020-12-31" ...
 $ start_date : Date, format: "2020-09-01" "2020-11-30" ...
```

Comment: Would be good to also show what is your expected output.

Comment: I think a for loop is the way to go using `set()` to update column classes if needed.

Comment: could you provide a solution as I am not super familiar with `set()` for-loops `data.table` syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option with set():

```
for (i in seq_along(dt)) {
  correct_type <- meta_dt[col_n == names(dt)[i], type]
  if (!inherits(dt[[i]], correct_type)) {
    if (correct_type %in% c("date", "Date")) {
      format <- meta_dt[col_n == names(dt)[i], form]
      set(dt, j = i, value = as.Date(dt[[i]], format))
    } else {
      set(dt, j = i, value = as(dt[[i]], correct_type))
    }
  }
}

> str(dt)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  4 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ id         : chr  "1" "2" "3" "4"
 $ description: chr  "ab" "ac" "ad" "ae"
 $ extension  : Date, format: "2020-01-01" "2020-12-31" "2020-05-01" "2020-01-04"
 $ start_date : Date, format: "2020-09-01" NA "2020-08-19" "2020-03-14"
```

Note that

- the correct class name for date objects starts with an uppercase `Date`
- `2020-11-31` is not a valid date in the Gregorian Calendar and is thus converted to `NA`.